# java referencing objects in an array

Tags: java, c++, arrays, algorithm, indexing

Is there a similar function to `indexof()` that will search a string array (preferably unsorted) for a string and return it's index? (or maybe ordinate value?)
for example i am trying:

```
String[] colours= {"Red", "Orange", "Yellow"};

System.out.println("indexOf(Red) = " +
        colours.indexOf("Red"));
```

...but having no success.
thanks.
AV
p.s. this will eventually need to work in a 2d array (in case that matters)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
String[] colours= {"Red", "Orange", "Yellow", "Green", "Blue", "Violet", "Orange", "Blue"};

Arrays.asList(colours).indexOf("Red"); // 0
```

OR
if order doesn't matter then

```
Arrays.sort(colours);   
Arrays.binarySearch(colours,"Red");//binary search takes sorted[natural order] array as input
```

- [List](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/List.html)
- [Arrays](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Arrays.html)

Comment: Doesn't work. List.get() will need an int parameter and will not search the array.

Comment: @Toa ah.. `indexOf` it should be

Comment: no binary search doesnt work, Arrays.asList(colours).indexOf("Red"); seems to

Comment: it takes sorted array as input I missed that point, so first one would be perfect for you

Answer (score 2):

For sorted arrays you can use Arrays.binarySearch: http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Arrays.html

For unsorted arrays `Arrays.asList(array).indexOf("String")` will do.

However this last method won't be very efficient as the list is going to be scanned sequentially.

Comment: And it will instantiate an ArrayList

Answer (score 0):

Frankly...

```
int findString(String[] stringArray;String match) {
  for (i=0;i<stringArray.length;++i) {
    if (match.equals(stringArray[i]) return i;
  }
}
```

will do you just fine. You could have written that in less time than it took to ask the question.